# What Geopartioning or distributed SQL database can I use?

Tags: distributed-databases

I want to split medical data on multiple nodes because I have Swiss, Europeans and Americans and I need to store data in citizen country.

I don't want to manage this function in App but in the SQL database engine.
The user’s table has a country code and automatically data are stored on good nodes/data center.

Do you have any solution to do this ?

Comment: Are you planning to use a Cloud Provider?

Comment: This question will likely be [closed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it's the quintessential *shopping list* question, meaning you're looking for a product or list of potential products that will solve your problem.  We often close these as these lists often get outdated quickly and this question quickly loses relevance as a result.  If you have a more specific issue in mind though, please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is medical data, I am going to make the assumption that you can afford a bit of a budget on this project?

I would suggest that you could do worse than taking a look at CockroachDB - from [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/product/sql/):

> With CockroachDB’s distributed SQL engine, your business can grow
>   without ever manually sharding. Keep your services running with a
>   database that automatically scales, rebalances, and repairs itself.

Their SQL engine is compatible with the PostgreSQL client, so anything that connects to PostgreSQL, can connect.

and with respect to Geo-distribution, you have from [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/product/geo-distributed):

> The easiest way to maintain compliance with global data regulations
>   Keep customer data where it needs to be. With CockroachDB’s
>   policy-based data controls like geo-partitioning, serving customers in
>   ever-changing geopolitical environments has never been easier or more
>   affordable.

and also this:

> Control Data Residency at the Row-Level Implement table and row-level
>   policies that dictate where a user’s data resides using CockroachDB’s
>   geo-partitioning.

They also have a managed offering if that would suit. I've used it for a Masters project and found it to be excellent - their documentation is superb (lovely graphic design!) and their support even for a lowly student on a free tier was great!

I also found that they were open about their product's [limitations](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/known-limitations.html), but appear to be working well to overcome these. I've used it on AWS, GCP and Azure with no problems.

Also, when I said "budget" above, I meant over and beyond what you'd be paying for a cloud provider anyway. With CRDB, there is a free option, but I would suggest that with sensitive medical data, you should pay a bit more for the extra [features](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/pricing/) of the pay version.

One of the guys who founded the company is [Spencer Kimball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencer_Kimball_(computer_programmer)) who, as a student, began writing the Gimp (Gnu Image Manipulation Programme), Open Source's answer to Photoshop! He then worked on the Spanner/F1 system in Google!

If this sounds like a commercial, it's not! I'm just a happy user who was blown away with what you got on the free (and Apache licenced Open Source) tier!

If you already have a system that works off MySQL, you might want to look at [TiDB](https://github.com/pingcap/tidb)! It's similar in scope to CockroachDB (not suprising as they're both based on Google's Spanner/F1 architecture). That is, if you can live with its [limitations](https://github.com/pingcap/docs/blob/master/sql/mysql-compatibility.md) which are, IMHO, a bit severe for production still - but, hey, have a look - I've also used it on AWS, GCP and Azure also

Comment: It might be a fine product, but the name is simply hideous.

Comment: You can't kill a colony (think cluster) of cockroaches! :-)